# Ipopt exits soon after starting without any error message

Tags: python, optimization, ipopt

I am testing a camera placement optimization problem using IPOPT in python. I am running it using anaconda in python 3.7 on MS windows. My objective function is:

```
def objective(particle):
  numControl = np.size(controlP,1)
  currVars = particle
  x = np.cos(currVars[0])*np.sin(currVars[1])
  y = np.sin(currVars[0])*np.sin(currVars[1])
  z = np.cos(currVars[1])
  C = np.array([x,y,z], dtype='f').transpose()
  heightParam = currVars[2]
  camDir = np.array([x,y,z-heightParam], dtype='f')
  camRight = np.cross(camDir, up)
  camUp = np.cross(camRight,camDir)
  R = np.concatenate((camRight[np.newaxis],camUp[np.newaxis],camDir[np.newaxis]), axis=0)
  t = -(R @ C)
  M_temp = np.concatenate((R,t[:,None]), axis=1)
  M = np.concatenate((M_temp,np.array([[0,0,0,1]])), axis=0)

  contSum=np.zeros(numControl)
  for i in range(0,numControl):
    p = M @ controlP[:,i]
    p = p/p[2]
    val1 = np.logical_not(lax.convert_element_type(lax.floor(np.minimum(p[0], 1.0)), bool))
    val2 = np.logical_not(lax.convert_element_type(lax.floor(np.minimum(p[1], 1.0)), bool))
    contSum = contSum.at[i].set(np.logical_and(val1, val2))
  return -np.sum(contSum)
```

Particle is a 1x3 vector (3 variables). The camera position (C) and camera transformation matrix (M) are calculated from these three variables. I have a set of 3D points (controlP), an array of size 4x2200. In the for loop, we check these points against M and when it satisfies 'val1' and 'val2' conditions, the corresponding entry in 'contSum' is set to 1. contSum is a vector with 2200 elements. **The objective is to maximize the sum of 'contSum'.**

**The optimization program however exits few seconds after starting, without any output or errors messages**. When I run the for loop for a smaller range, say for i in range(0, 500), the optimizaiton completes with a 'found optimal solution' message. The variables and bounds are initialized like this:

```
x0 = np.array([0, 0, 0]*dims)        # starting point
    bnds = [(0,2*np.pi-0.0001), (0,np.pi-0.0001), (0,1)]*dims
    obj_jit = jit(objective)
    res = minimize_ipopt(obj_jit, x0=x0, bounds=bnds, options={'disp': 5, 'max_iter':100})
```

Here's a screenshot of the output during crash [image: crash_output]

Comment: Maybe it ran out of memory?

Comment: I was monitoring my task manager, but the RAM usage was almost constant between 52%-56% until the program was running. So, I guessed its not an out of memory problem.

Comment: `'disp': 5` could be the Ipopt print_level. A higher value might give you more output before it terminates.
Also you could check with the developers of the Python/Ipopt interface that you are using whether they can reproduce this. Maybe they can also give some hint on how to debug.

Comment: I missed mentioning in the post, but I checked with 'disp' : 12 as well. There aren't any additional output messages printed at this particular point of crash. When the program exits its still the same output messages. I now opened a new issue at cyipopt's Github page https://github.com/mechmotum/cyipopt/issues/181